# Make model authenticable when it is extending another class

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `spatie/laravel-event-sourcing` in my app. I have `Consultant` model which extending `Projection` (abstract) class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Projections;
use Spatie\EventSourcing\Projections\Projection;

class Consultant extends Projection
{
```

I made auth guard for `Consultant` model and using breeze login I getting this error:

`Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, App\Projections\Consultant given`

It is thrown because Consultant should extend `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`

How I can extend two classes?
`Projection` and `User`

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-event-sourcing/discussions/372

I know that php doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Problem is that core laravel code and package have type check of classes, so traits can't solve this issue. I can move functionality, but some methods still  expects argument type of `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` or `Spatie\EventSourcing\Projections\Projection`

Comment: I think you should make the Consultant model extend Authenticatable and make a trait for the Projection functionality and make the two models use it

Comment: or you can make the user model is the root model to auth and if you have customer make another model (table) and make the relation between user and customer one to one and each actor in the system should have another table with one to one relation with user so it can make login and other functions you need

Comment: you just need to implement the interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for tips,
the only solution was create another class, and implement all needed data:

```
<?php

namespace App\Contracts;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Spatie\EventSourcing\Projections\Projection;

class AuthenticableProjection extends Projection implements
    AuthenticatableContract,
    AuthorizableContract,
    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable;
    use Authorizable;
    use CanResetPassword;
    use MustVerifyEmail;
}
```

but unfortunately in next step I'm getting project specific exception and the only way to fix it is to rewrite authentication logic. I won't do that, instead of it I will create another model and make relationship between them

```
Spatie \ EventSourcing \ Projections \ Exceptions \ ReadonlyProjection
The `App\Projections\Consultant` projection is not writeable at this point, please call `$model->writeable()` first.
```